# Where are all the hats?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

Unlike the first game, Find Mii II has branching paths and multiple ways to reach the end boss.

I want to get as many hats as possible in as few playthroughs as possible, so knowing where the hats are located would be a great help.

Which areas give you a hat once you complete them?

Comment: wait. what. Did anyone say ___hats?___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/nintendo-3ds/Find_Mii_II) on IGN has all the details you need to know to succeed in Find Mii II, including two illustrations showing the locations of all hats in the standard quest and secret quest.

Find Mii II hats:
[image: Find Mii II hats]
Find Mii II secret quest hats:
[image: Find Mii II secret quest hats]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is at least one hat on each prong of every fork. Since there are paths that split into three, this means you must have at least 3 playthroughs to get all the hats.

> I believe this also applies to the secret quest, so that's another 3 playthroughs.